# trouble with registration using yii framework

Tags: php, yii, registration

I'm trying to implement user registration using yii ActiveRecord. the problem is that every time the view is being loaded i get the following exception:

```
User has an invalid validation rule. 
The rule must specify attributes to be validated and the validator name.
```

here is the relevant part from the Users model:

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('username, password,verifyCode,email','message'=>'Tidak boleh kosong'),
            //array('password','compare'),
            array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'required', 'allowEmpty'=>!extension_loaded('gd')),
            array('level_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('username', 'length', 'max'=>20),
            array('password, email', 'length', 'max'=>50),
            //array('password_repeat','required'),
            array('avatar', 'file', 'types'=>'gif,png,jpg'),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, username, password, email, joinDate, level_id, avatar', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

Controller:

```
public function actionRegister() {
    $registration = new RegistrationForm("register");
    // collect user input data
    if (isset($_POST['RegistrationForm'])) {
        $registration->attributes = $_POST['RegistrationForm'];
        $registration->attributes = $_POST['RegistrationForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if ($registration->validate()) {
            // create an account model
            $account = new User;
            $account->username = $registration->username;
            $account->password = $registration->password;
            $account->email = $registration->email;
            $account->joinDate = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
            //$account->level_id = 1;
            if ($account->save()) {
                $member = new Member;
                $member->attributes = $registration->attributes;
                $member->user_id = $account->id;
                if ($member->save()) { 
                    $this->redirect(array('index'));
                } else {
                    $registration->addErrors($member->getErrors());
                }
            } else {
                $registration->addErrors($account->getErrors());
            }
        }
    }
    $this->render('register', array('model' => $registration));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you missed a validator in your first rule. As I think, you missed the required validator.

So you need to change this:

```
array('username, password,verifyCode,email','message'=>'Tidak boleh kosong'),
```

To something like this:

```
array('username, password,verifyCode,email','required','message'=>'Tidak boleh kosong'),
```

Another mistake is, that your using the [captcha validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCaptchaValidator). Captcha can only be used in a view with a [CFormModel](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormModel), a [CCaptcha Widget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCaptcha) and a [CCaptcha action](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCaptchaAction).

If you want a file upload, that isn't required, you need to add the [allowEmpty](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileValidator#allowEmpty-detail):

```
array('avatar', 'file', 'allowEmpty' => true, 'types'=>'gif,png,jpg'),
```

Comment: @DeboraPanggabean: And what is it? Do you get some exceptions?

Comment: i got error like this Property "CCaptchaValidator.0" is not defined.

Comment: @DeboraPanggabean: Why do you have a captcha in your user-model? I think this needs to be in your form. And if you need a captcha anywhere, you need to leave the `required`

Comment: so, should i comment this?

Comment: @DeboraPanggabean: Yes, you need to delete the captcha rule. If you're having another problem, please tell me

Comment: @DeboraPanggabean: Does it work. It would be nice, if you can give me a feedback.

Comment: so, should i comment this?

Comment: @DeboraPanggabean: Comment the captcha? Yes, because without, it will not work

Comment: i have comment thi but something wrong with my form

Comment: @DeboraPanggabean If you write `something`, I can't help you, you need to tell whats your problem. As Example an error message...

Comment: i got errors again like taht Please fix the following input errors:
    Tidak boleh kosong
    Avatar cannot be blank.
whereas i have already fill that, but

Comment: @DeboraPanggabean This is because you did not what your rules are expecting. I think `Tidak boleh kosong` is because you didn't fill out all of your `required` fields. For the `Avatar` error, I edit my answer

Comment: but my registration form doesn't need that i mean not display avatar field and the verify code still ask me to fill that whereas i have already fill that

Comment: @DeboraPanggabean: Are those rules from a CActiveRecord (models/User.php?) or from a CFormModel? In your question your saying, that them are from a CActiveRecord but if you tell me that you want to fill your form data directly into this model, it must be a CFormModel. Perhaps, you don't know the differences between those two, but then, you need to read the documentation: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/11486-cformmodel-and-cactiverecord-differences/

Comment: thank's for your answer, i will study carefully, i'm difficult to undersatnd this because i'm a beginner